# Labeling each bar in a ggplot bar graph when using the fill aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these data, which are included at the bottom of the post with `dput()`

```
> head(df)
   variable    value     nCore   nPeriph   FK90
1 Core1Cone 88.00222 359.65000  97.71667  24.28
2 Core1Cone 78.26995  79.76667  42.55000  39.90
3 Core1Cone 76.16143 461.71667 102.28333  42.56
4 Core1Cone 68.66943 209.43333  45.98333  78.31
5 Core1Cone 34.65022 487.68333  38.10000  99.27
6 Core1Cone 53.46456 250.63333  61.38333 103.93
```

And with the code below, I can make the following figure where the bars are labeled with`nCore`

```
library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(FK90), y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC3322", "#66CCFF"), labels=c("Core", "Periphery"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 24, face = "bold"), legend.text=element_text(size=16), legend.position=c(0.88,0.91),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=18), axis.title.y=element_text(size=18), axis.text=element_text(size=14))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=df$FK90)+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(nCore)),vjust=1.5,position=position_dodge(.9),size=5)
```

[image]

However, I want only the red bars labeled with`nCore` and the blue bars to be labeled with the `nPeriph` field.

Any suggestions on how to label each bar with a different field would be appreciated.

```
df <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Core1Cone", 
"Outer1Cone"), class = "factor"), value = c(88.0022244, 78.269954, 
76.1614266, 68.6694254, 34.650217, 53.4645565, 36.4734627, 36.1200483, 
24.9019273, 81.786134, 46.4070393, 14.1718014, 27.5590551, 32.0934021, 
0, 68.9482225), nCore = c(359.649999823245, 79.7666666746877, 
461.716666608, 209.433333469832, 487.683333152032, 250.633333316376, 
122.783333278669, 331.533333438411, 359.649999823245, 79.7666666746877, 
461.716666608, 209.433333469832, 487.683333152032, 250.633333316376, 
122.783333278669, 331.533333438411), nPeriph = c(97.716666876755, 
42.5500000253123, 102.283333392, 45.9833332301678, 38.1000001479679, 
61.3833333836244, 12.7500000213309, 112.983333261589, 97.716666876755, 
42.5500000253123, 102.283333392, 45.9833332301678, 38.1000001479679, 
61.3833333836244, 12.7500000213309, 112.983333261589), FK90 = c(24.28, 
39.9, 42.56, 78.31, 99.27, 103.93, 135.34, 169.19, 24.28, 39.9, 
42.56, 78.31, 99.27, 103.93, 135.34, 169.19)), .Names = c("variable", 
"value", "nCore", "nPeriph", "FK90"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: couldn't you make another variable that is equal to nCore or NPeriph depending on whether they are red/blue and use that for the labeling?

Comment: not sure I follow completely...? Post as answer...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as requested

```
df$newvar <- ifelse(df$variable=='Core1Cone', df$nCore, df$nPeriph)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(FK90), y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#CC3322", "#66CCFF"), labels=c("Core", "Periphery"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 24, face = "bold"), legend.text=element_text(size=16), legend.position=c(0.88,0.91),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=18), axis.title.y=element_text(size=18), axis.text=element_text(size=14))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=df$FK90)+
  geom_text(aes(label = round(newvar)),vjust=1.5,position=position_dodge(.9),size=5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an `ifelse()` statement to `geom_text`

```
+ geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(variable=="Core1Cone", round(nCore), round(nPeriph))), vjust=1.5, position=position_dodge(.9), size=5)
```

[image]